# Eclipse web project not working after converting to Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have an Eclipse web project that was working perfectly fine until I converted it to a Maven project. Previously, I could make changes to a servlet, restart Tomcat from the Eclipse Servers tab, and then browse to my localhost to view the page. Any changes I made to a JSP file were reflected immediately on page reload.

After converting to a Maven project, when I make a change to a Java file, the .class file under the build directory is not updated, even though I have Build Automatically selected. If I delete the .class file, it does not get rebuilt. If I try to view the webapp in a browser, I see a ClassNotFoundException for the servlet class.

I have spent a lot of time going through the project's properties and searching online, but I can't figure out how to get this working again. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I fixed part of the problem by moving my source files from project_root/src to src/main/java. Now I can build the project using Maven, but I still have to manually copy the class files to my local tomcat's webapp directory. If anyone knows of a way to automate this, I would like to hear it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using m2e and m2e-wtp for Maven integration in Eclipse?

Comment: I know I'm using m2e, I'm not sure about m2e-wtp.

Comment: You need both.  If you import your Maven project into Eclipse and it doesn't show up with a dedicated `Deployment Descriptor:` entry, then you don't have m2e-wtp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by moving my source files from project_root/src to src/main/java and then making sure that src/main/java was on the build path under Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source tab. Eclipse now deploys my changed files to the proper directory under .metadata so the changes show up in my local instance of Tomcat. @davidfmatheson, thanks for your comments, I will look into using m2e-wtp.

Answer (score 0):

You might have incorrect output folder for generated java classes in your java build path.
it should be yourprojectname/target/buildfoldername/WEB-INF/classes.
Select your project->Properties->java build path->source->change the output folder the src/main/java to the above path.